# Can We Write test Class for RecordsetVar with StandardController?

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, standardsetcontroller

Vf page with recordsetvar :

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="Accounts" sidebar="false">
  <apex:form id="form">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts List">
      <apex:pageblocktable value="{!Accounts}" var="Acc" rows="5">      
        <apex:column headerValue="Name">
            <apex:commandLink value="{!Acc.name}" rerender="page" >
                <apex:param name="aid" value="{!Acc.id}"   />
                <apex:param name="aname" value="{!Acc.name}"   />              
            </apex:commandLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!Acc.type}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!Acc.industry}"/>
    </apex:pageblocktable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
     <apex:pageblock id="page" title="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.aname}">
    <apex:detail subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.aid}" relatedList="false"/>
    </apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: may i know the objective of you testing the standard controller functionality ?

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no controller involved in this ,there is no need to write any test code for this page .

A test class is needed if you have apex controller linked to the Visualforce Page .